# Correct semantic tags for content in grid - html5

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What would be the most semantic tag to display the **text** contents of the following image grid?

I going to implement it in either flexbox or css-grid and I'm searching a better way than just wrap the keywords in div-tags.

[image: image grid]

Here's my current code (used flexbox)

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap gridcontainer">
<div class="gridimage">
    <img src="placeholders/img16.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="gridkeyword">
    <p class="gridkeyword__keyword">Process-Oriented</p>
</div>
<div class="gridkeyword">
    <p class="gridkeyword__keyword">Valence</p>
</div>
<div class="gridimage">
    <img src="placeholders/img12.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="gridkeyword">
    <p class="gridkeyword__keyword">Quality</p>
</div>
<div class="gridimage">
    <img src="placeholders/img18.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is very much semantic value you could squeeze out of this beyond the <p> elements you already have. If it's a list of core values, you could *maybe* put each image/text pair in an <li>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images don’t convey any relevant information, you would ideally add them via CSS. If that’s not possible, you should provide an empty `alt` attribute.

If they do convey relevant information, they should have a suitable `alt` attribute; if it would be the same as the visible keyword, the `alt` attribute should be empty.

You could provide a list, representing what’s good about the business:

```html
<!-- images are decoration, added via CSS -->
<ul>
  <li>Process-oriented</li>
  <li>Valence</li>
  <li>Quality</li>
</ul>
```

```html
<!-- images are decoration, or the 'alt' would be the same as the keywords -->
<ul>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /> Process-oriented</li>
  <li>Valence <img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li>Quality <img src="" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

```html
<!-- images are relevant -->
<ul>
  <li><img src="" alt="Our machines … foobar." /> Process-oriented</li>
  <li>Valence <img src="" alt="We … foobar." /></li>
  <li>Quality <img src="" alt="The best … foobar." /></li>
</ul>
```

Add `span`/`div` elements and `class` attributes as needed for styling.

If the images are of importance (doesn’t seem to be the case according to your screenshot, though), you could consider using `figure` with `figcaption`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this is by wrapping each word within a DIV since you will have greater control over each word.